# Is there any way to scroll a very long video (using the mouse) more precisely than how It's done by default in VLC?

Tags: vlc

As the title says, is there any way to scroll a **very** long video (using the mouse) more precisely than how it's done by default in VLC?

Scrolling for long videos sometimes is either imprecise and "jumps" too far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't...

To have that kind of fine control, you'll have to use the keyboard with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in combination with <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> for very short, short and medium jumps respectively

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...*